# Webclient on download of a file throws "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send"

Tags: c#, .net, webclient

I am using VS2008 on windows 2k3. I am trying to download a file using webclient. When downloading google's logo I am able to download it.However, the code throws the following exception when downloading from other server.
**The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send**.
I do not have the option of setting the securityProtocol as I am using old .net (3.5).i.e 
`ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;` 
 
I also tried running the code on windows 2k8, and it works fine there.

 Following is the code snippet.

```
 using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                client.Proxy = WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy();
                client.DownloadFile("https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_120x44dp.png", @"D:\dwimg.png");
            }
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem in your code. The problem is the link you are downloading data from. Google doesn't allow frequent calls from any machine, It treats such request as spam, the calls from some web spiders/crawlers etc.. who are trying to fetch data from their site, that is the one reason google doesn't allow you to download data from their page no matter it's an image or anything which is available on their page.

Trying to download data from some other site will not give you such error.

Comment: Hi @M Adeel Khalid : The code works when downloading the file from Google server, and fails to download when used on other server.

Comment: Can you explain this line a bit "when used on other server"?

Comment: I can't really say which server, but the connection to the server(Say X) uses TLS 1.2.Just like the case where Googles logo is publicly available. The image on the other server is also publicly available. The only difference i could find is the connection on google is encrypted using AES_128_GCM and on **X** the connection is encrypted using AES_256_CBC